# Can a Scalding source select a subset of the files in an S3 bucket to process?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce, cascading, scalding

I have a Scalding job which operates on all the files in a particular timestamped S3 bucket. It looks like this:

`JsonLine("s3://path/to/timestampedbuckets/2016-02-03/", ('key1, 'key2)).read`

I want to alter the job to operate on the files in several of these timestamped buckets at once. For instance, to operate on all the files in 2015 and 2016, I would like to do something like this:

`JsonLine("s3://path/to/timestampedbuckets/201[56]-*", ('key1, 'key2)).read`

or, more generally, this:

```
def shouldProcess(path: String): Boolean = {...}
ChoosyJsonLine("s3://path/to/timestampedbuckets/", filepath => shouldProcess(filepath), ('key1, 'key2)).read
```

So is it possible for a Scalding job to selecively process only some of the files in the input S3 bucket?

Comment: In my experience its easier to pass the list of buckets/paths to process as a comma separated list.

Comment: While it would be possible to write a script to list all the buckets within the range and use that as the input to the Hadoop job, I would prefer the cleaner approach of doing everything in one jar.

Comment: I think what Dan meant was something like
`val paths = (2015 to 2016 map List("s3:/path/",_,"*").mkString("/") mkstring(",")`